# Не могу запустить загрузку картинок с вк через json

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не могу запустить загрузку картинок с вк через json...Все отображается, кроме картинки...Мой пикассо вроде работает, но картинки не отображает(((( Подскажите что нитак??

Делаю так:

```
VKRequest reqWall=VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, -1, VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100 , "text"));
            reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
            reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response)
                    {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                        String owner = null;
                        try {
                            owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        VKPostArray posts = new VKPostArray();
                        try {
                            posts.parse(response.json);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        VKApiPost p = posts.get(0);
                        VKAttachments at = p.attachments;
                        VKAttachments.VKApiAttachment test = at.get(0);
                        try {
                            Log.v("test", (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("profiles")).get(0)).getString("id")));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userWall);
                        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        RecyclerAdapterWall adapterWall = new RecyclerAdapterWall(getApplicationContext(), posts);
                        rv.setAdapter(adapterWall);
```

==============

```
public class RecyclerAdapterWall extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterWall.ViewHolder>{
    Context ctx;
    String owner_id;
    VKPostArray obj;

    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts){
        //super(ctx,R.layout.recycler_item_wall);
        this.obj= posts;
        this.ctx= ctx;

    }
    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts, String owner_id){
        //super(ctx,R.layout.recycler_item_wall);
        this.obj= posts;
        this.ctx= ctx;
        this.owner_id= owner_id;

    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final VKApiPost p= obj.get(position);
        holder.imageWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
        java.util.Date time= new java.util.Date((long)p.date*1000);
        holder.textDatePost.setText(String.valueOf(time));
        try{
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(String.valueOf(p.attachments.get(position))).into(holder.imageWall);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cv;
        TextView textNamePost;
        TextView textDatePost;
        TextView textPost;
        ImageView imageWall;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);
            textDatePost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            //textNamePost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNamePost);
            textPost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
            imageWall=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageWall);

        }
    }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Столько времени потратил на ожидание ответа и так и не дождался такого простого ответа.....

Пока ждал, все сделал сам.....

```
public class RecyclerAdapterWall extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterWall.ViewHolder>{
    Context ctx;
    String owner_id;
    VKPostArray obj;
    Picasso picasso;

    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts){

        this.obj= posts;
        this.ctx= ctx;

    }
    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts, String owner_id){

        this.obj= posts;
        this.ctx= ctx;
        this.owner_id= owner_id;

    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        VKApiPost p= obj.get(position);
        try{
            VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
            att = p.attachments;
            VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto)att.get(0);

        holder.imageWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
        holder.textlikePost.setText("Лайкнули: " + p.likes_count+ "     " + "Поделились: " + p.reposts_count);

        java.util.Date time= new java.util.Date((long)p.date*1000);
        holder.textDatePost.setText(String.valueOf(time));

        picasso.with(ctx).load(photo.photo_604).into(holder.imageWall);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cv;
        TextView textlikePost;
        TextView textDatePost;
        TextView textPost;
        ImageView imageWall;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);
            textDatePost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            textlikePost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLikePost);
            textPost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
            imageWall=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageWall);

        }}}
```